# Change another div style based on the check box check/uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

This problem is bugging me too much and I can't get rid of it.

I want to Change the background color of a DIV only when a visitor checks first two check boxes form a list of 10.

```
HTML:
           <div id="position_6">
                <div id="circle">                   
                    <p class="circle_text">

                        #6                       
                    </p>
                </div>               
             </div>

<br/><br/>

        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox1" name="Checkbox1"/> Answer one <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox2" name="Checkbox2"/> Answer two <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox3" name="a3"/> Answer three <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox4" name="a4"/> Answer four <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox5" name="a5"/> Answer five <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox6" name="a6"/> Answer six <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox7" name="a7"/> Answer seven <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox8" name="a8"/> Answer eight<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox9" name="a9"/> Answer nine <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox10" name="a10"/> Answer ten <br/>
```

Any luck on this??

So far what I tried is bellow:

```
// JavaScript Document

function bubbleColor() {

    if($("#Checkbox1").is(":checked") && $("#Checkbox2").is(":checked")) /
    {
        $("circle").css("text-decoration", "red");

    }
}
var el = document.getElementById("circle");
el.onclick = bubbleColor;
```

Comment: Any of the first two or both of them?

Comment: Tried sort of JS with no luck

Comment: This seems pretty similar to one of your previous questions mate. That was for color and this is for background color. I guess you can work out the logic.

Comment: // JavaScript Document

function bubbleColor() {
 
 if($("#Checkbox1").is(":checked") && $("#Checkbox2").is(":checked")) //etc do this for each checkbox up to 7
 {
  $("circle").css("text-decoration", "red");
  
 }
}
var el = document.getElementById("circle");
el.onclick = bubbleColor;

Comment: @DannyThunder : both of them

Comment: `css("text-decoration", "red");` is wrong. You should set `background-color` and not `text-decoration`.

Comment: oh! sorry harry, Just tired to tweak. But none of them changes the style

Comment: It should be `$("#circle")` and not `$("circle")`. You have to use `#` to select an element with `id` as circle. If you just use `circle`, it will check for an element `tag name` as circle.

Comment: @Harry: Noting works!

Comment: And now, just wondering how many #circle element do you have on your page? Is at least your click event fired?

Comment: @MohammadKhalidMasud: Ok, *nothing works* helps nobody. Look into the Dev Console, check if there are any errors reported. Let us know about it and it will be easier to debug.

Comment: @A.Wolff: I didn't think about it before. I have 10 #circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$('#Checkbox1, #Checkbox2').on('change', function () {

    if ($('#Checkbox1').is(':checked') && $('#Checkbox2').is(':checked')) {
        $('#circle').css('background-color', '#999');
    } else {
        $('#circle').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/G77Kb/)

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but you should get the jist. Add a change event to both checkboxes and add a class depending on whether it is checked or not or change the css directly.

```
$(function(){
   $('#Checkbox1, #Checkbox2').change(function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $('#DIVidHere').addClass('altBackground');
         //Or change css
         //$('#DIVidHere').css('background-color','#000000');
      } else {
         $('#DIVidHere').addClass('altBackground');
         //Or change css
         //$('#DIVidHere').css('background-color','#FFFFFF');
      }
   });
});
```

**Please Note** - currently this doesn't check that both have been checked. I presumed it was one or the other?

Comment: both should be checked

Answer (score 0):

You can try with attribute selectors like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name^="Checkbox"]').on('click', function () {
       if($(':checked').length >= 2){
           $('#circle').css('background-color','red');
       }
    });
});
```

This can check only those checkboxes whose name starts with `Checkbox` and if length is `>= 2` then `#circle` div will get the background color of `red`

[You can take an idea from here](http://jsfiddle.net/TDj2w/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're doing with the onclick event as you need to be watching the checkboxes but I think you might want something like this.

```
   $('#Checkbox1, #Checkbox2').change(function(){
    if($("#Checkbox1").is(":checked") && $("#Checkbox2").is(":checked")) /
    {
        $("#circle").css("text-decoration", "red");
    }
   });
```

In your example you have the event on clicks on the div rather than the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#Checkbox1, #Checkbox2").change(function(e) {
    if($(this).attr('id')=="Checkbox1") {
        $("#circle").removeClass("blue").addClass("red");
        $("#Checkbox2").prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        $("#circle").removeClass("red").addClass("blue");
        $("#Checkbox1").prop('checked', false);
    }
    if(!$("#Checkbox1").is(":checked") && !$("#Checkbox2").is(":checked"))
        $("#circle").removeClass("red blue");
});
</script>

<style>
.red { background-color:red; }
.blue { background-color:blue; }
</style>
```